# How to fix boot failure due to incorrect fstab?

Tags: rhel, boot, mount, fstab

It seems that I have added incorrect record to `/etc/fstab`:

```
//servername/share    /mnt/share    cifs     defaults,username=myuser     0 0
```

When I did `mount -a`, it asked user password to mount network share. It seems that it cannot proceed without password on boot, so it is just hung.

How can I fix fstab to prevent boot failure?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It seems that I’ve found a solution:

- At the GRUB prompt, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to append options.
- Add `init=/bin/bash` to the end of the kernel command line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The system will boot to a prompt like `bash-3.2#` enter the following commands at the prompt

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then edit the fstab:

```
vim /etc/fstab
```

Edit the fstab file commenting the errors by adding a # at the begining of each problematic line, save the file and reboot by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: I had to use `mount -o remount,rw / --target /` to succesfully remount in rw mode. Elsecase mount was picking the bad values from `/etc/fstab`, see the `man mount` for details.

Comment: @laconbass you are damn right, `--target /` is the key!

Comment: This is still true today - over six years later. Anyway on CentOS7 the key for changing an entry on boot is now tab, and once on bash you have to mount your filesystem (which is still unmounted at this stage) with a simple `mount /dev/sda(X) /mnt` (obviously changing the root partition with the right one)

Comment: Saved my life..

Comment: So if a mount is inaccessible at boot - Linux won't Boot? We are seeing weird services like `sssd` fail if a completely unrelated mount fails.

Comment: On RHEL 8 variants. Hit `e` on the kernel selection screen and you will get the grub prompt. The line to append `init=/bin/bash` is the one starting with `linux`. The rest is as per OP

Answer (score 3):

How about removing the entry, creating a snapshot and then trying to change your /etc/fstab so you have a working snapshot you can roll back to?

According to the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) `mount.cifs` you can also specify a password via `password=arg`. Also, according to that manpage there is no argument `username=arg`  but instead `user=arg`. But it might be different on your system, better check your manpage for the correct argument names.

Comment: `man` for the win.

Comment: I was about to create snapshot, but while I was experimenting with `fstab`, vm instance went off for some reason. Apparently, I wouldn't ask the question if I could fix it myself.

Comment: Your problem description is a little bit unclear. Can't you boot in single user / recovery mode? It should only try to mount the root fs and leave the fstab alone.

Answer (score 1):

The other easy way is booting to live-cd mode and mount the right partition. Then you can fix anything you want!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to systems error kernel not loading
Use live cd to gain access to your existing installation. Once in reinstall Linux kernel :

```
pacman -S Linux
```

Then delete the fstab file from etc/fstab :

```
rm /etc/fstab
```

Now reinstall systemd:

```
pacman -S systemd
```

When reinstalling systemd it will automatically generate a new fstab file

Now reinstall the bootloader 
in this case I use grub:

```
pacman -S grub os-prober
```

(os probe is useful if you have more than 1 os installed on your hdd/ssd)
 Then

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
```

Once finished make the configuration files:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Then unmount the partitions in use and reboot

```
umount /dev/sdX 
reboot
```

This should fix the problem, it worked for me.