# How can I edit root /etc/fstab after boot failure in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, boot, fstab

After an incorrect record was added to `/etc/fstab`, CentOS is, expectedly, failing to boot.

I've been looking around and found a [lot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185026/how-to-edit-etc-fstab-when-system-boots-to-read-only-file-system) of [different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44027/how-to-fix-boot-failure-due-to-incorrect-fstab) [solutions](https://www.systutorials.com/39557/bypassing-bad-fstab-failure-while-booting-linux/) but I'm unable to resolve my issue.

When editing the kernel file for CentOS, I press `e`, and I am presented with this file:

[image: Kernel]

I've tried different combinations of adding `init=/bin/bash` or `rw` or `single`, etc. to the `linuxefi` line, but mostly I end up on a screen that prompts for a passphrase:

[image: Passphrase Prompt]

I don't have the passphrase for this, and I am looking for a password-less option of editing the bad `/etc/fstab` file.

If I enter an incorrect password three times, I'm entered into a version of emergency mode, however I can't edit `/etc/fstab`, only a file `/etc/fstab.empty` exists, which is, unsurprisingly, empty.

[image]

Edit: The following information is how we are installing CentOS in the first place, which I believe may indicate that we are encrypting the hard disk, which I think means that I am stuck...

Using `text` mode:

```
# Secure Boot Mode:
part /boot/efi --fstype="efi" --size=200 --fsoptions="umask=0077,shortname=winnt"
part /boot     --fstype="xfs" --size=200
part /         --fstype="xfs" --grow --encrypted --passphrase=temppass
```

Later:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup HDD Encryption
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
yum install -y clevis clevis-luks clevis-dracut
# Entries from previous installs can remain and cause problems:
luksmeta nuke -f -d /dev/sde3
# Move decyption to the TPM:
clevis luks bind -f -k- -d /dev/sde3 tpm2 '{"pcr_ids":"7"}' <<< temppass
echo -n temppass | cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sde3 -
dracut -f
```

Comment: Hi @sourcejedi, I included some of the installation steps that we have in our kickstart file (created by someone we have lost contact with), I'm hoping this may inform you of our setup for the root filesystem.

Comment: The password you are getting is for your encrypted root volume. The commands you list removed the unlock password so you have to let it decrypt via the tpm chip, there is no other option. If that doesn’t work, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The messages say the initrd is failing to mount `/sysroot`, which will become the root filesystem that contains `/etc/fstab`. if that's because you don't know the password for it - I think you're  stuck.

I'm not familiar with the kickstart commands, but I guess you're right to think the hard disk is encrypted.